# Where to get visa for US

Tags: visas, usa

A friend of mine is a permanent resident living in Spain, but she holds a Chinese Passport. If she wants to come to US for a visit. Which US Consulate or Embassy should she go to get her visa? Many thanks !

Comment: One in Spain, whichever is easiest for her to get to.  Where does she live?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with the embassy of the target country you want to move to, in the country you currently reside.
So in your case, that would be an US Embassy or Consulate in Spain.

Comment: There's also a consulate general in Barcelona.  Is there any reason she shouldn't go there?

Comment: Barcelona is a city in Spain, @phoog

Comment: Don't let the Catalonians hear you say that, @Aganju. :-)

Comment: @Aganju I'm aware of that.  There's a US embassy in Madrid and a US consulate in Barcelona; either would be equally suitable as far as I can see.

Comment: I misunderstood your first comment, sorry. Yes, that works too.

Comment: Thank you to you both @Aganju and phoog ! She lives in Alicante, but I will ask her to check with US consulate in Barcelona first. It would be great if she can apply for the visa there, if not I'm sure they will give her a definite answer as to where to go.